# sql return empty although there is no error

Tags: sql

I am working in a jsp file and I have those following tables for the sql

```
- idea(IdeaID, Title, Type, IsApproved, ... , OwnerID)
- project(PID, ..., IdeaID)
- ideaowner(ID, Name, ...)
- managerrequestidea (IdeaID, MangerID)
```

what I want the sql to do is to retrieve every idea that isn't in the project table, and the "IsApproved" attribute is true, and any idea that isn't already requested from the user(Manager)

my sql:

```
String sql = "select idea.IdeaID, Title, Type, Name from idea, project, ideaowner, mangerrequestidea m where idea.IdeaID<>project.IdeaID and IsApproved=1 and ID=OwnerID and idea.IdeaID=m.IdeaID and m.MangerID<>" + userId;
//userId is an int of the logged user ID
```

the project table is empty at the moment, so I don't know if it would affect it.

For example:

```
ideaowner
    (ID, Name)
    (1, mat x)
    (2, susan y)

idea
    (IdeaID, Title, Type, IsApproved, OwnerID)
    (1, an application, Application, 1, 1)
    (2, a software, Software, 0, 1)
    (3, a software, Software, 1, 2)
    (4, a website, Website, 1, 2)

Project
    (PID, IdeaID)
    (1,3)

managerrequestidea
    (IdeaID, MangerID)
    (4, 2)
```

In jsp

```
userId= 2; //susan
```

What I should get

```
(1, an application, Application, mat x)
```

What I really get

```
//Nothing
```

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: please clarify,what is the use  'idea.IdeaID<>project.IdeaID'  in join?

Comment: The idea can become a project if it gets a manger to manage it, so I don't want to show any idea that has already become a project

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: 'idea.IdeaID<>project.IdeaID' is not going to behave the way you expect especially once you have more than one project. From your description you want something like  idea.IdeaID not in (select project.IdeaID from project). You'll also need to remove project from your where clause otherwise you'll have a cartesian product.

Comment: Oh!! I will try it, but what if it returned empty when the  project is empty wouldn't it give an exception?

Comment: it worked thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query, rewritten to explicit joins would look like this:

```
"select idea.IdeaID, Title, Type, Name 
 from idea
 inner join project on idea.ideaid <> project.ideaid
 inner join ideaowner on idea.ownerid = ideaowner.id
 inner join managerrequestidea m on idea.ideaid = m.ideaid
 where 
   and idea.IsApproved = 1
   and m.MangerID <> " + userId;
```

You get an empty result set for `userId = 2`, since your `managerrequestidea` only contains one row with `MangerId` = 2, and you are applying a filter in `WHERE` clause to exclude that ID.

There is no need for any more evaluation since your first fiter on `managerrequestidea` results in 0 rows. And 0 rows multiplied by any number of rows equals 0.

You probably need different data or filters for this query to work.

Comment: Yeah forgot about that, but another user (Eponyme Web) used nested sql would it work then? For both the project and managerrequestidea connections even if the nested sql returned empty?

Comment: Try it yourself I would say, but it is a pattern to follow. The data must meet joins and where conditions in order to show up.